# DrawerLayout : Open new activity without closing drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a problem when selecting the listview item in my drawer. What I want to achieve is that, when I click the item. It should open a new activity. But the drawer still remain. In my case, it open as new window. Here's my code :

```
    drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {
            String sel = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            textSelection.setText(sel);

            selectItem(position);
        }});

public void selectItem(int position) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
        case 1: {
            Intent j = new Intent(jav_mainform.this, jav_joform.class);
            startActivity(j);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            Intent i = new Intent(jav_mainform.this, jav_joform.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use fragment.It will remain in same page.As your are using activity its opening new page

Comment: Do you have any example @yuvaツ?

Comment: check it - http://javatechig.com/android/navigation-drawer-android-example , https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behaviour of `DrawerLayout`. You need to hide drawer yourself after starting activity.

```
mYourDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```